# Why some function have been called

Tags: apache-flex, builder

1 Create a project use flex sdk 3.4

2 Create a new mxml app Testadd.mxml

3 Add a source jpg Any.jpg

content of Testadd.mxml just two line.

```
  [Embed(source="Any.jpg")]

public var NotUsedSource:Class;
```

I think this just defined a class which represent some data. And I never use it or initialize any instance of it in this app.

4 Profile this app, when it is profiling I click the resize button of IE servral times.

5 From the profiled data a function named Testadd_NotUsedSource.flash.events:IEventDispatcher:dispatchEvent is been called

6 My question is why this function has been called.

I have the screenshot but can't add to this post.

Comment: I think that, by nature, embedding the asset in this manner means you added an instance of it to your app; even if you never used said instance elsewhere.  Have you tried this profile case w/o the embedded asset?  I would suspect that the dispatchEvent relates to the resize event, not the embedded asset.

Answer (score 1):

If the application is resizing, it's dispatching resize events.  If there are any controls inside it, they might also be dispatching resize or moving events.

If you're moving your mouse around, it's dispatching mouseMove events.

Events happen a lot, it's normal.